# Python tz aware str to datetime object for resample calculation

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

- I have the following tz aware strings.
- I would like to to use the data.resample('D') operation on this data.
- I am having some trouble getting it into the right format. I've tried using pd.to_datetime but I get the following error when trying to use resample.

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

```
>>> test1['timestamp']
0        2017-01-03 08:30:00-06:00
1        2017-01-03 08:30:32-06:00
2        2017-01-03 08:30:42-06:00
3        2017-01-03 08:30:46-06:00
4        2017-01-03 08:30:52-06:00
                   ...            
65334    2017-12-29 14:55:02-06:00
65335    2017-12-29 14:55:26-06:00
65336    2017-12-29 14:55:54-06:00
65337    2017-12-29 14:59:23-06:00
65338    2017-12-29 14:59:46-06:00
Name: timestamp, Length: 65339, dtype: object
```

What's the best way do accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Tried pd.to_datetime to convert from obj (string) to datetime dtype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message starts with *Only valid with **DatetimeIndex**,...*.

So after you convert *timestamp* column to *datetime*, create
a *DatetimeIndex* from it (and save it for future use):

```
ind = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp))
```

The result is:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-03 08:30:00-06:00', '2017-01-03 08:30:32-06:00',
               '2017-01-03 08:30:42-06:00', '2017-01-03 08:30:46-06:00',
               '2017-01-03 08:30:52-06:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-360)]', name='timestamp', freq=None)
```

Or maybe you should set the index in your DataFrame, based
of the above formula:

```
wrk = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)))\
    .drop(columns=['timestamp'])
```

and then reindex it (with some aggregation function), e.g.:

```
wrk.resample('15s').sum()
```

I created the source *df* as:

```
                   timestamp  amount
0  2017-01-03 08:30:00-06:00      12
1  2017-01-03 08:30:32-06:00      14
2  2017-01-03 08:30:42-06:00      17
3  2017-01-03 08:30:46-06:00      19
4  2017-01-03 08:30:52-06:00      23
```

and got the following result:

```
                           amount
timestamp                        
2017-01-03 08:30:00-06:00      12
2017-01-03 08:30:15-06:00       0
2017-01-03 08:30:30-06:00      31
2017-01-03 08:30:45-06:00      42
```